# Repeating UVs wont convert to texture in maya

Tags: textures, maya

I have designed a material in Maya which i want to convert to a texture jpg, however i have repeating the UV's on the material. When i convert the material to a jpg the repeating UV's wont convert across. Is there anyway i can get them too?